# how to convert the spectrogram into an image

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

using MATLAB, we have converted image into audio (.wav format). Also this audio file is converted into spectrogram image. Now we are trying to convert this spectrogram into an original input image

Comment: Good luck with that.  If you could explain a bit more about your problem, perhaps tell us what file formats you are using (apart from the wav you mentioned) and what operations you hope to perform.  I'm also confused by your attempts to convert 'into an original input image'.  Perhaps you mean you want to recover the original image from the spectogram.  More explanation please.

Comment: Question is too vague - provide more specific details and you may get some help

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230906/reverse-spectrogram-a-la-aphex-twin-in-matlab?

Comment: spectrogram functions should return a 2d array of time and freqency, just plot them as x y of bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, and if the spectrogram was built over non-overlapping "sliding windows", you can then simply do the inverse FFT for each time chunk and combine them to recover the audio signal. Then you perform the inverse of the operation you did to covert image to audio.